# Start a program using subprocess with all windows hidden

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I'm using subprocess on Windows to start IrfanView to convert a TIFF file to a PDF using command line switches.

I'm working through a few folders of TIFFs and am calling the command for each file. When saving the PDF, IrfanView displays a dialog titled 'Save PDF' to show the progress.

The dialog only shows for a split second but grabs the window focus so the computer can't be used while my script runs in the background. I've tried using `subprocess.STARTUPINFO` values to hide the window and while the dialog is now hidden it still seems to grab focus.

Here's how I'm calling the IrfanView application.

```
startup_info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO
startup_info.dwFlags = 1
startup_info.wShowWindow = 0

subprocess.call(['i_view32.exe', 'c:/input.tif', '/convert=c:/output.pdf'], startupinfo=startup_info)
```

Does anybody know of a way of starting an application with its windows hidden and without it stealing focus? I'm happy to try a few things - even a wrapper application that then calls IrfanView would do if such a program exists. I'm only needing this for Windows so I don't need a cross-platform solution.

I know I could also use GraphicsMagick or similar instead, but IrfanView does a better job at matching the compression format of the input file so ideally I'd like to get this working using IrfanView.

Comment: `shell = False` See http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

Comment: Thanks, but that makes no difference. `shell` is set to `False` by default.

Comment: Windows allows you to create a second desktop and start a subprocess there.  I don't know whether you can call the necessary APIs in Python.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the application supporting a non-interactive mode.   `subprocess` can prevent calls from opening a console window when starting an application, but it can't prevent the application itself from opening a window.

Googling irfanview returns an [article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-useful-commandline-irfanview-tools-working-images/) describing the "hide" command line option - it's possible that hide=15 would sort of do what you want, at the risk of leaking a bunch of invisible zombie windows.  The program apparently does not have a real /batch option that would refrain from opening dialogs or other windows in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'd tried that, but the `hide` command line option is for hiding IrfanView UI elements such as the toolbar. The dialog I'm seeing is actually from the PDF plugin (ImPDF) and there don't seem to be any command line options to pass to IrfanView to control its UI.